# Keep images with size set to percentage on the same scale with window resize

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, webapp2

I am building a web app. The size of the images are set using percentages. I have three images overlapping another image that is used as the toolbar. When I have the images display with my browser on full screen, they look fine. However, when I have them displayed with my screen smaller, the ratio of image size to screen seems to change. What can I do to change this?

Full size:[image: Full size version]

Smaller size version:

[image]

Notice the difference in size of the icons.

My code:

```
<div id="bottombar" data-position="fixed">
                    <img id="ico" class="foodico" src="images/icons/Food1.png" width="3%">
                    <img id="ico" class="shopico" src="images/icons/Shop1.png" width="3%">
                    <img id="ico" class="activityico" src="images/icons/Activity1.png" width="3%">
                    <img id="Bbackground" src="images/icons/NavBarBackground.png" width="100%" height="7.8%">
                </div>
```

Comment: You have multiple elements with the same id `ico`. ID's are used for unique elements in the DOM. You should change that to class instead.

Comment: I want them to resize, but am doing something wrong. I'm quite new to web app programming, coming from native programming. I want the proportion to stay the same after re size. See how before resize, they are almost touching the top of the bar. After, they are tiny and no where near the top. I'm less concerned with the percentage staying the same, I just want the proportion to be the same regardless of what they are resized to. Maybe I need some javascript?

Comment: Can you post your css associated with this issue. Even better if you can make a jsFiddle.

Comment: I shall make a js fiddle now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the `height` to a set amount, they won't become smaller unless the container they're in has its `height` attribute reduced.

Comment: Thanks! But now that the height is set, upon resize, the images become disproportionate.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vj2Fr/2/ The `width:auto;` will keep its proportions in check. See the fiddle for an example.